# Dynamically passing JSON value to another template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have one template, let's call it **Template A** that prints JSON data into a table, one column includes a button which is conditionally rendered when `has_violations` equals true.

An example of the table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlwiN.png)

What I want to accomplish is to take the `driver_id` that is associated with that particular row into the router link and have it passed onto a different template file let's call it **Template B**.

But how can I accomplish this using Vuex Store?

Sample JSON data:

```
{"driver_id":1,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"13","driver_trailer":"83","driver_status":"driving","has_violations":false},
{"driver_id":2,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"58","driver_trailer":"37","driver_status":"sleeping","has_violations":true},
{"driver_id":3,"driver_name":"{driver_first_name}, {driver_last_name}","driver_truck":"80","driver_trailer":"27","driver_status":"driving","has_violations":true},
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps:

1. Get index of row on button click.
2. Get index of JSON data using value from Step 1.
3. [Store the JSON data from Step 2 into Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).
4. Send user to Template B using router.
5. Retrieve data from Store when in Template B

Because you did not show your exact structure, the code below is just a basic structure.

Here's the code:

```
/* VUEX demo */
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    driver_data: undefined
  },
  mutations: {
    recordDriver({ state }, payload){
      state.driver_data = payload;
    }
  }
});


/* TEMPLATE A demo */
new Vue.component('template-a', {
  data: function(){
    return {
      // Assume this is the JSON
      driverJSON: [
        { driver_id: 1, driver_name: 'John Smith' },
        { driver_id: 2, driver_name: 'Bob John' }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onButtonClicked: function(e){
      const button = e.target;
      const td = button.parentElement;
      const tr = td.parentElement;
      const indexOfTr = [...tr.parentElement.children].findIndex(row => row === tr);

      const dataToStore = this.driverJSON[indexOfTr];

      // Store data into $store
      this.$store.commit('recordDriver', dataToStore);

      // After storing, direct page using $router
      this.$router.go({ ... });
    }
  }
});


/* TEMPLATE B demo */
new Vue.component('template-b', {
  data: function(){
    return {
      // Get driver data using $store
      driver: this.$store.state.driver_data
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Yong's answer, but I would rather suggest you to pass the driverID as a prop to your route and then use a VueX getter to get the violations for the particular ID.